# Continual wake and sleep for minimal power usage on linux?

Tags: linux, sleep, power-saving

I'd like to use a linux pc purely to collect rss feeds, but would like to minimise it's power usage as much as possible.

Presumably I would create some kind of cron job to bring it in and out of sleep mode or are there better ways of tackling this?

Comment: Does cron work even when the system is sleeping?

Comment: No, cron won't work when the system is sleeping, so you'd have to wake the system up just before the cron job is due - see vartec's post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set wake up alarm in RTC, then put the computer in standby or suspend(-to-RAM) mode. Some motherboards support waking up from hibernation (suspend-to-disk), but I guess that'll be  too slow.

```
echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 5 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
echo -n "mem" > /sys/power/state
```

Replace "mem" with "standby" for stand-by instead of suspend.

BTW. MythTV's wiki has got some more in-depth info end examples.
http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup

Comment: You could suspend to disk if the power taken to save and suspend is less than the power that would be consumed powering the memory in suspend-to-ram mode.

Comment: There are two problems with suspend-to-disk: 1. not all BIOSes support RTC wakeup in hibernation, 2. it means dumping all occupied memory to disk on suspend, and then loading it on wake. That is time and power consuming.